# sql server: create table taking forever!

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE person
     ( 
        num               INT              NOT NULL  , 
        firstname         VARCHAR(20)          NULL  , 
        lastname          VARCHAR(30)          NULL  
        );
```

sql server is just saying "debbuging" and it's not doing anything

is there a problem with the syntax or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You clicked on the 'Debug' button (green triangle) instead of 'Execute' (red exclamation)? SSMS is waiting on you to step through the T-SQL lines.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are locks on the database that would prevent SQL Server from executing a `create` statement.  Since you're creating a new table, check for a database-level locks.

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest the obvious...try restarting sql server?